# CPU usage at 100% with ZeroMQ publisher (C)

Tags: c, cpu, zeromq

I'm writing a ZeroMQ Publisher in C that sends a single message in a while loop. I set its high watermark as "20":

```
int sndhwm = 20;
size_t sndhwm_size = sizeof(sndhwm);
int rc = zmq_setsockopt(publisher, ZMQ_SNDHWM, &sndhwm, sndhwm_size);
```

I wrote this piece of code before the `bind`. After the bind, I print the value of the watermark, just to make sure it was set:

```
int sndhwm2;
size_t sndhwm_size2 = sizeof(sndhwm2);
rc = zmq_getsockopt(publisher, ZMQ_SNDHWM, &sndhwm2, &sndhwm_size2);
printf("sndhwm: %i\n",sndhwm2);
```

It prints the result correctly.

However, when I run the program, CPU usage is almost always at 100%.

[image]

I noticed this does not happen if, after every `send`, I execute a `sleep(1)`, and then CPU usage is pretty close to 0%.

What could be the problem here?  Why is the CPU core at 100%? Is it related to the set watermark?

**edit:** I'm using libzmq3-dev version 4.2.5.

**edit2:** My apologies, for some reason I mistook the memory leak with the CPU core usage. I edited the question accordingly.

This is the reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "zhelpers.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv []){

    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);

    char buffer[50];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");

    int sndhwm = 20;
    size_t sndhwm_size = sizeof(sndhwm);
    int rc = zmq_setsockopt(publisher, ZMQ_SNDHWM, &sndhwm, sndhwm_size);

    rc = zmq_bind(publisher, buffer);

    int sndhwm2;
    size_t sndhwm_size2 = sizeof(sndhwm2);
    rc = zmq_getsockopt(publisher, ZMQ_SNDHWM, &sndhwm2, &sndhwm_size2); 
    assert(rc == 0);

    while (1){
        rc = s_send(publisher, "hello"); 
        //sleep(1);
    }

    zmq_close(publisher);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code where you call send also, along with any relevant data structures that are used/allocated there (basically a [mcve]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tight loop like that will usually lead to 100% CPU. Why do you think it shouldn't?

If you add the `sleep()` your process will go to sleep for 1 second on each iteration. This is a very long time for a CPU and CPU usage will usually go to 0%, if no other intensive processes are running.

When the publisher socket reaches the high water mark, I think it will just drop any new messages. This is basically a no-op (no operation), which gives a tight loop and this leads to 100% CPU usage.

If you do not see 100% CPU usage when you *do not set* the high water mark, I think the publisher will keep buffering new messages, especially if no subscribers are connected. This involves memory allocation, which is a relatively slow operation. This could give a lower a CPU usage as the CPU has to wait on memory, swapping to disk, etc..

Comment: I would bet you will see 100% CPU-core utilisation even when having infinitely large **`ZMQ_SNDHWM`** as the loop will still remain devilish fast ( until swapping starts )

Answer (score 1):

To control the behaviour you can tell the pub socket to inform you if the send operation failed due to a full buffer. That way you can decide when to sleep your loop.

You need to.

- Pass the flag `ZMQ_DONTWAIT` on `zmq_send`
- Check `zmq_send` return value for failure (-1)
- If you get failure check the errno (to determine between hitting HWM and a real error)

BTW I am not sure what `s_send` will return is but it's probably best to use the functions provided in libzmq or cppzmq.